# GNU Make ignores environment variables on windows

Tags: powershell, makefile, gnu-make

So, in powershell, I type

```
$ Set-Variable FOO
```

Then, in my makefile, I have

```
.PHONY: show-foo
show-foo:
    @echo ${FOO}
```

It outputs a blank line.

I've tried using system variables like $profile, none of the environment variables seem to be passed into the makefile.

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

On windows 10, using make 4.2.1

Comment: Which `make` do you use? MSYS2, Mingw, Cygwin?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer GNU Make https://chocolatey.org/packages/make

Comment: Not a powershell expert, but I think `Set-Variable` may not change the environment, just set a shell variable? Try `$env:FOO="VALUE"` instead?

Comment: @OndrejK.Hot diggity, you're right! If you want to add this as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Sure, let's close the loop on this one. Happy it helped, esp. since I REALLY am not a Windows person. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Set-Variable` sets a shell variable, but does not modify the environment (just like `var="val"` in `sh` without exporting would). Instead use

```
$env:FOO="VALUE"
```

to manipulate the environment.

Comment: alternatively, `Set-Item -Path Env:\FOO -Value VALUE`.  PowerShell really likes its drives system.